# Read all the files from a folder starting from 2nd file in Java

Tags: java, file

I have few files in a folder and I want to read the first file and perform some operations and after the first iteration, I want to read files from the 2nd one on wards to perform different set of operations.

How can I do this?

```
    File folder=new File(Folder);            
    File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();          

        for(File file:listOfFiles)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        //Here I want to read from the 2nd file to do different set of operations
```

Comment: Understand that there is no guarantee in the order of the files, running the code twice could generate two different results

Comment: What is the first file according to your requirement? Is it the first file sorted alphabetically?

Comment: No. Its just few XML files where I should read each XML file from the folder to generate the report. 
Basically I need to compare the results of each XML in two different environment. 
So, when I read the first file, it should open both the environments in a window .. So now it has 2 tabs open, and from 2nd file on wards I should just continue the execution without opening a new window and login and stuff.

Comment: use a variable to save the *environment* (e.g. the window) and start with `null`. In the loop, if it is `null`, create  and assign the *environment*. After the first time, the variable will not be `null` and so that operation is only executed once (and it is quite clear for any one reading the code). Eventually you can/should use just a boolean flag instead of the *environment*...

Answer (score 2):

Get the first file as `listOfFiles[0]` and do the operation1 on it.

Then, use a simple (regular) *for* loop starting at index 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
   File currentFile = listOfFiles[i];
   //do Operation 2 with currentFile
}
```

Note from the [javadoc of **Files.listFiles**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--)

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Comment: But I'm using the file name for few things. In that case, how can I extract the file name?
If I use for(File file:listOfFiles), I can get the filename "file".

Comment: I don't understand your question. *listOfFiles[i]* will give you a *File*

Comment: Yes I do know to use Arrays

Comment: @JavaUser Inside the loop use file.getName() to retrieve the name of the file

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, it seems like you don't need the list of files to be sorted in some particular order before you process them. In that case,

```
File folder=new File(Folder);            
File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();          

//use a normal for loop to keep track of the index
for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++){
   //the file in the current index of iteration
   File currentFile = listOfFiles[i];
   if(i==0){
      //Do something with first file
   }
   else{
      //Here I want to read from the 2nd file to do different set of operations
   }
}
```

In the above code put the operation code for first file in the *if* block and the code for rest of the files in *else* block

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `java.io.File` anymore, use `java.nio`—it's been around for a couple of years now! Beside the easier use—including Java 8 streams, one benefit is that you're not restricted to the system's default file system. You might even use an in-memory file system like Google's *JimFS*. As pointed out by other's, there is no guarantee on the order of files. You *may* however introduce your own sorting:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault(); // use a file system of your choice here!
Path folder = fs.getPath(...);

Files.newDirectoryStream(folder)
     .sorted((a, b) -> { ... })
     // this realizes the skipping of the first element you initially requested:
     .skip(1)
     .forEach(f -> { ... });
```

If you want to perform action A on the first element and action B on the second, it might get a litle trickier: you might define a boolean `firstFileHasBeenProcessed` as external dependency, that's gonna be set to `true` once you processed the first file, but I am *not* sure if the consumers for all files will run strictly sequential—or if the processing of the first file may be interrupted to start processing the seond, before that flag could be set.

You can always render a stream to an array ...

```
final Path[] allFiles = Files.newDirectoryStream(folder)
                      .sorted((a, b) -> { ... })
                      .toArray(Path[]::new);
```

... or a list, though, to gain more control.

```
final List<Path> allFiles = Files.newDirectoryStream(folder)
                          .sorted((a, b) -> { ... })
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean firstHasBeenProcessed = false;
for (final Path currentFile: allFiles) {
    if (firstHasBeenProcessed) {
        processAsFollowUpFile(currentFile);
    } else {
        processAsFirstFile(currentFile);
        firstHasBeenProcessed = true;
    }
}
```